# Encode live range in DWARF

Tags: compiler-construction, gdb, dwarf

I want to encode live range of a variable in DWARF. How should I do it?
I see in spec, page 178 of DWARF 3 pdf that DW_AT_high_pc and low_pc are not applicable to DIEs tagged with TAG_variable. Where should I encode it according to spec?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can do.

One is that you can emit a block and have the variable appear in the block.  When the block ends the variable will be out of scope.  This is the simplest approach if you aren't doing complicated optimizations.

Another approach is to use DWARF location lists to represent the live ranges of variables.  See section 2.6.2 ("Location Lists") of the DWARF 4 standard (they were in DWARF 3 as well, I don't have that right here to look it up though).